# Ember: How to merge an UnwatchedDir with a tree / unwatch a subdirectory?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, broccolijs

I want a subdirectory of a directory (say `public`) to be unwatched for changes.

In order to unwatch a directory itself, in my `ember-cli-build.js`, I'm doing `app.trees.public = new UnwatchedDir('public')` before return.

But how can I unwatch only a subdirectory inside `public`?

I did the below, but doesn't work.

```
var publicMinusLocales = new Funnel('public', { exclude: ['assets/locales'] });
var unwatchedLocalesTree = new Funnel(new UnwatchedDir('public/assets/locales'));
var mergedTree = new BroccoliMergeTrees([publicMinusLocales, unwatchedLocalesTree], { overwrite: true })
app.trees.public = mergedTree;
```

Comment: what is the expected outcome of unwatching a directory?

Comment: Live reload will not be triggered if files in the unwatched folder change.

Comment: And you want live reload to not be triggered if that public directory changes?

Comment: I want a specific sub-directory of the public directory to not trigger live reload. `app.trees.public = new UnwatchedDir('public')` stops live reload for the entire public directory.

Comment: When you say it didn't work, what was the outcome? Was there an error message?

Comment: No errors. It just didn't stop watching `public`.

Comment: is it *absolutly necessary* for that directory to be inside `public`? I would place it as a sibling to `public`, and then use `MergeTrees` on the actual public to merge them. Maybe with `Funnel` to place it in a subfolder.